# missing notification after npm run commands

Tags: laravel, npm, notifications, vagrant

If I'm inside vagrant and homestead for laravel, I do not get any notifications after an npm commands run. If I'm not in vagrant everything is okay. What should be the problem in this case?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Homestead is Vagrant box that uses Ubuntu as guest OS. There are some security measures that don't allow a virtual machine to push notifications to your host OS, and this is for your sake.

It is better to run npm from your host OS.

Comment: So basically it is not problem to rely on the developers host OS? For example somebody use windows some other linux or osx when running these kind of commands?

Comment: @AttilaSzendi, unless there are some OS specific related commands, it should be fine. But this can be covered too, depending of OS ( you can check it with "os" package, with .type() method ),  and then apply different commands for different OS.